# An Operations Error Occured When trying to retrieve data from active directory

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I'm trying to get the manager name from the active directory but am receiving the error "An operations error occured" when it throws the exception.

Code is below:

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   base.ItemAdding(properties);

   try 
   {
      var requester = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

      properties.AfterProperties["Requester"] = requester;

      //Get the manager name from the active directory
      var domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
   DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);
      //Exeception occurs on this line below.
      string managerName = dir.Properties["Manager"].Value.ToString();

      properties.AfterProperties["Manager"] = managerName;

   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
```

**Edit**
Was able to get this figured out using the code below:

```
try
    {
        // set up domain context
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // find a user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Environment.UserName);
        string samAccountName = "";


        if (user != null)
        {
            // do something here....     
            samAccountName = user.SamAccountName;
        }


        //Get the manager name from the active directory
        var domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

        using(DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(dir, "samAccountName=" + samAccountName))
            {

                SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

                string managerName = result.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
            }
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: `Properties` is an object you need to cast that for starters
`string managerName = (string)dir.Properties["Manager"].Value.ToString();` also how do you know what the error really is when you have no code in the catch for example `var message = ex.Message;` can you post the full code within that method also `use the Debugger` and step thru each line verifying that you do in fact have valid data / values

Comment: When stepping through when I debug I see what the exception is when it gets to the catch. I'll try your suggestion though

Comment: only trying to help Ryan I know AD very well and what I am seeing looks like you're missing something also in your LDAP://` line are you missing the `389` address in your conn string

Comment: I know :), thanks. I'll edit the code a bit to include the method but there's really not much else in there, it's mostly just the try catch for now.

Comment: There you go DJ, updated the code to include the rest of the method.

Comment: It still gives me the exception when I try the string casting, anymore ideas :) DJ?

Comment: try changing this line `string managerName = dir.Properties["Manager"].Value.ToString();` to `var managerName = dir.Properties["Manager"].Value;` also what is the value of domain from this line `DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);`

Comment: the domain is dev.mycompanyname.com

Comment: does it actually connect and give values for `dir` variable?

Comment: I dont believe so, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: you need to pass the domain name `dev.mycompanyname.com:389/CN=Configuration,DC=demo,DC=local"` you need to make the changes to match the `CN, DC, DC=Com` for your environment here is a link that you can reference as well` http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

Comment: I need to check one more thing on my end I will see how my current project connects to our AD

Comment: Thanks! Only thing is your link doesn't work for me, maybe the site isn't up anymore?

Comment: I just tried the link let me put it in a different format here you can click on this here on the link to the right [AD/Ldap stuff](http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm)

Comment: Still a no go on the link, not sure why :S.

Comment: where are you located..? I am in USA TX wonder if you have ISP restrictions

Comment: ha you should have issues getting to it.. unless you are at work and they block certain site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the Manager from the domain, not from requester.

In a winform I would do it like this assuming that requester == samAccountName:

```
       try
        {

            //Get the manager name from the active directory
            var domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
            using (DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(dir, "samAccountName=" + requster))
                {
                    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
                    //Exeception occurs on this line below, if the attribute is not set.
                    string managerName = sr.Properties["Manager"][0].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Still getting the same exception when it tries to do the ds.FindOne(), it might have something to do with the domain, it's just dev.mycompanyname.come.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7569603/1027551  Does it work in a Winform?

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out actually using part of your solution, I'll post my solution if everything works. Thanks!